# How much slang is acceptable in a question or answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

The answer posted by Thomas Chen for the question below has several slang words and phrases. The OP doesn't have an origin specified in their profile. I want to downvote it because of the slang and add a comment explaining why I'm doing so but is that a reasonable course of action?

[Possible choices for switching programs in the same university](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/200221/possible-choices-for-switching-programs-in-the-same-university) (original, pre-edit text below):

> Blimey, it sounds like you're in a **bit of a pickle**. Remember though, you're not alone in this. Kick off by having a **natter** with your advisor about the whole thing - they're there to give you a hand. If your current programme isn't **tickling your fancy**, you might want to consider switching to something that gets your motor running.
>
> Try to sort out any disagreements with your professors, even if it seems like a **tall order**. You'll feel much better once everything's out in the open. If you're still worried about the grading, consider asking for a second look - you've every right to understand your marks. Don't overlook your mates, either - they're there for advice or even just a good **chinwag**. If things get too intense, don't hesitate to seek professional advice. It might seem a bit overwhelming now, but keep your eye on the ball. You've got this, mate!

Examples: *in a pickle, chinwag, natter, tickling your fancy, tall order,* ...

I do understand all of the slang but only because I've read and watched media from various English-speaking cultures.

Comment: I edited the answer to make the language more "regular" and in the end also mor accessible for non native speakers. After all, I consider it one of the perks of this site that it is possible to edit content. And in 99% of the time, the OP doesn't object the edit or reverts the text back to the original form.

Comment: I try to avoid unnecessary big words, for the sake of clarity. And I prefer literal language. But how people learn big words and idioms and slang is largely from hearing other people use those. So it probably doesn't make that much sense to, in essence, try to ban those things. Although if you feel a post is so filled with such things that it would be incoherent to many English speakers, that may warrant a downvote.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I didn't like the tone of the answer and it felt more like an experiment to fit as much idiomatic language in as possible rather than answering the question, so I downvoted it.

It's not appropriate to downvote a user that you don't like or because they left a critical comment on a post of yours. But if you don't find an answer useful relative to the question asked, you don't really need more than that to justify a downvote. We rely on the opinions of the masses to help good content rise to the top.

For a single idiom or slang usage where you think you can improve an answer without hurting the meaning, it would be more appropriate to use the edit feature and replace it with something more readable. I sometimes have a bad habit of using that sort of language myself and appreciate when someone helps improve the readability of what I've posted.

Comment: It sounds like someone asked ChatGPT to pretend it's British.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-: Good point.  The Cockney jargon aside, the real problem with the answer was that its advice was vague and inane - just like ChatGPT.